# phonegap command not found on mac

Tags: cordova

I installed phonegap as well as nodejs as prompted by the install guide. the installs went smoothly however the next step would be to create my first app. the guide states to run 'phonegap create -p my-app' which I did. Doing so produced the following error:

-bash: phonegap: command not found

any ideas? I think the problem may lay in my path, I remember trying to run something else from the terminal and it wouldn't work properly displaying a similar message...

any and all thoughts are helpful.
thank you,
Dan

Comment: What's in your $PATH? Also, what does `which phonegap` and `which npm` display?

Comment: Check if your phonegap is correctly installed? `phonegap -version`